# Else statement is always being executed

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader

For some reason my Else statement is always being executed even when the if statement is.

```
string line;
string[] columns = null;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    columns = line.Split(',');
    if (columns.Contains(tboxName.Text))
    {
        rtBoxResults.Text = ((columns[0] + " " + columns[1] + " " + columns[2] + " " + columns[3]));
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Hotels Found.");
        break;
    }
```

Is this because it is searching through every line in the file because of the while loop and not every line contains tboxName?

If so how would it be able to return all values of column[0] without using a while loop?

Comment: did you trim your textbox value and splitted values?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to show the message box if *none* of the lines in the file contain `tboxName.Text`? If so you can do this check after the while loop completes, using a `bool` to track whether any line did have a match:

```
        string line;
        string[] columns = null;
        bool foundHotels = false;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            columns = line.Split(',');
            if (columns.Contains(tboxName.Text))
            {
                rtBoxResults.Text = ((columns[0] + " " + columns[1] + " " + columns[2] + " " + columns[3]));
               foundHotels = true;
            }
         }

         if(!foundHotels)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("No Hotels Found.");               
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
string[] columns = null;
        var isHotels = false;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            columns = line.Split(',');
            if (columns.Contains(tboxName.Text))
            {
                rtBoxResults.Text = ((columns[0] + " " + columns[1] + " " + columns[2] + " " + columns[3]));
                isHotels = true;
            }
        } // while loop ends
        if (!isHotels)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Hotels Found.");
            break;
        }
```